# Using the BeautifulSoup find method to obtain data from a table row

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am writing a Python script using BeautifulSoup to scrape values from this webpage: https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels

I want to use soup.find() to get values for "Hourly mean Nitrogen dioxide" and "Last updated" from the table row where the "Monitoring site" is "Edinburgh St Leonards".

As I am new to web scraping I am having a bit of trouble so would be grateful for any help on this.

Comment: Describe the *trouble*

Comment: I have tried using a number of different html attributes e.g. class="centre" but am unsure which I need to use and how to specify that they belong to the table row of interest

Comment: show your code, what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of the suggestion from d2718nis, you can do it in this way. Of course, many other ways would work too.

First, find the link that has the 'Edinburgh St Leonards' text in it. Then find the *grand*parent of that link element, which is a `tr` element. Now identify the `td` elements in the `tr`. When you examine the table you see that the columns you want are the 4th and 7th. Get those from all of the `td` elements as the (0-relative) 3rd and 6th. Finally, display the crude texts of these elements.

You will need to do something clever to extract properly readable strings from these results.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> page = requests.get('https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels', headers={'User-Agent': 'Not blank'}).content
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> Edinburgh_link = soup.find_all('a',string='Edinburgh St Leonards')[0]
>>> Edinburgh_link 
<a href="../networks/site-info?site_id=ED3">Edinburgh St Leonards</a>
>>> Edinburgh_row = Edinburgh_link.findParent('td').findParent('tr')
>>> Edinburgh_columns = Edinburgh_row.findAll('td')
>>> Edinburgh_columns[3]
<td class="center"><span class="bg_low1 bold">20 (1 Low)</span></td>
>>> Edinburgh_columns[6]
<td>05/08/2017<br/>14:00:00</td>
>>> Edinburgh_columns[3].text
'20\xa0(1\xa0Low)'
>>> Edinburgh_columns[6].text
'05/08/201714:00:00'
```

Answer (score 2):

Scrap all the html tables in a list of tables. 
The table index may change, then you should not rely on a row/column index.
A part of the folowing script look up for the index of the searched data. Moreover, it prints the header name: so you know want are the data you get.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re

with urllib.request.urlopen('https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels?view=region') as response:
   htmlData = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlData, 'html5lib')

tables = soup.find_all('table', attrs={'class':'current_levels_table'})

#what you want to check:
Iwant = ['nitrogen', 'update']
about = 'Edinburgh'
for table in tables:
    #get header to have the data (we're looking for) column number and table real names
    table_head = table.find('thead')
    headrows = table_head.find_all('tr')
    measures = headrows[1].find_all('th')
    for colnum, measure in enumerate(measures):
        index.update({colnum: measure.text.strip() for wanted in Iwant if re.search(wanted+'(?iu)', measure.text)})
    #get table content and look for Edinburgh
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cels = row.find_all('td')
        rowContent = [cel.text.strip().replace(u'\xa0', u' ').replace(u'\n        Timeseries Graph', u'') for cel in cels if cel]
        if re.search(about+'(?iu)', rowContent[0]):
            for indexwanted, measurewanted in index.items():
                print(measurewanted, ':', rowContent[indexwanted])
```

Answer (score 0):

you can start with this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Request the page, set headers to prevent 403 Forbidden
page = requests.get(
    url='https://uk-air.defra.gov.uk/latest/currentlevels',
    headers={'User-Agent': 'Not blank'})
# Get html from page
html = page.text
# BeautifulSoup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')

for table in soup.find_all('table'):
    # Print all tables on the page
    print(table)
```

Comment: `html.parser` doesn't parse the html file. Your soup just has the first row and first column of each table (check it!). Consider using `html5lib`